# R shiny app showing package error

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, install.packages

I have developed a shiny app using R. When i run the app in the local server it runs well but after installing shiny server in a different remote server when i run the app it shows error:there is no library called 'xyz'
Please help!.

Comment: You have to install this library on this remote server.

Comment: how do i install the library?

Comment: because i have logged in the server where i installed shiny-server there in the console i type R and installed the required packages but still i am getting the same error

Comment: If there wasn't any errer, it should work than.

Comment: yeah thats what my concern is there is no error still it shows this weird error? what to do?

Comment: Did you reopen your application after installing packages?

Comment: yeah tried everything... I even restarted my computer and even then no luck...

Comment: Did you try to load this library in R on this remote server?

Comment: how do i do the last one u said?

Comment: You access your console on the server, type R and than just `library("xyz")`. Is there error than?

Comment: No thats the weird thing right?

Comment: my app uses 5 packages googleVis, data.table,zoo,shiny,rjsonio and the error keeps changing as in first it was for rjsonio then for zoo now for googleVis

Comment: How do you load your libraries? One by one or everything by one command?

Comment: everything by one command

Comment: Try to do it seperetly. But it is strange, I addmit. And I think, I can't help you, sorry.

Comment: tried it but did not work out... Can you gimme your facebook id in case i get stuck somewhere else i would appreciate your help

Comment: Check out [this article](http://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/) about hosting on Digital Ocean. Dean talks about how to properly install packages on a remote server so that they're available. My suspicion is that the way you're installing the packages is what's giving the errors.

Comment: Hey thanks a ton it worked.. I was installing the packages inside the R console and doing it without actually using R console solved the issue :D

Comment: I hope you understand *why* you were getting the error. Just to expand: the easiest solution is what my blog post suggests - to use `sudo ...` from the terminal to install a package. But you *can* install the package from the R console, if you either (a) specify the `lib` argument in `install.packages()` or (b) are logged in as the `shiny` user instead of your own user or (c) are logged in as `root`. If this comment is just confusing, don't worry about it :)